# MySQL Import CSV (Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'Escalation_date' at row 1", 1292)

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime, import

I've exported some rows from a table in order to simulate a Import from CSV into MySQL Table.
Rows are like this:

```
Number;Opened;Opened by;Source;Caller;Location;Category;Subcategory;Priority;Incident state;On hold reason;Assignment group;Support vendor name;ID vendor ticket;Escalation date;Parent Incident;Problem;Resolved;Resolved by;Closed;Closure CI;CI Closure Code;Sub CI;Sub Closure CI;Resolve time;Duration
INC0028837;2019-01-02 07:01:35;User1;Portal;User2;Location1;Category1;Sub_Cat1;3 - Moderate;Closed;;Assignment1;;;;;;2019-01-02 09:43;Resolved1;2019-01-05 10:00:00;;;;;9742;9742
```

I made some stored procedure that will update last columns when called.
My DB structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `incident_raw_data` (
  `Number` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `Opened` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Opened_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Source` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Caller` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Subcategory` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Priority` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Incident_state` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `On_hold_reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Assignment_group` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Support_vendor_name` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_vendor_ticket` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Escalation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parent_Incident` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Problem` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Resolved` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Resolved_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Closed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Closure_CI` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CI_Closure_Code` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sub_CI` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sub_Closure_CI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Resolve_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Opened_weekeday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Resolved_weekeday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Closed_weekday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Opened_hour` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Aging` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Gruppo_creatore` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gruppo_risolutore` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Check_SSG/SSG` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Aging_<5` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Aging_hh` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Number`),
  KEY `Resolve_time_index` (`Resolve_time`),
  KEY `Duration_index` (`Duration`),
  KEY `Opened_weekeday_index` (`Opened_weekeday`),
  KEY `Resolved_weekeday_index` (`Resolved_weekeday`),
  KEY `Closed_weekday_index` (`Closed_weekday`),
  KEY `Opened_hour_index` (`Opened_hour`),
  KEY `Aging_index` (`Aging`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Table B has the same structure in order not to tamper with original data and to perform some tests.
When I use the Import Wizard from Workbech, everything is correct except that when I've a EMPTY value in field Escalation_date, wizard tells me:

> (Row import failed with error: ("Incorrect datetime value: '' for
>   column 'Escalation_date' at row 1", 1292)

I've disabled STRICT_MODE both global and session(`SET @@global.sql_mode = '';`), but still import fails.
I've also tried to modify the csv, putting '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in the corresponding column, but i get the same error.
So i failed to understand which is the correct way to import this csv file.
Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this similar problem, discovering that MySQL `DATETIME` fields in particular don't like CSV empty values. I ended up working around it by replacing `,,` with `,NULL,` within the CSV file.